# Using zip & *, sort the list 'books_borrowed' alphabetically while ensuring that reference to the respective 'isbn' value remains the same in PYTHON

Tags: python, list, sorting, unzip

new_value= list(zip(books_borrowed,isbn))

book_sorted, isbn_sorted = list(zip(*new_value))

book_sorted= sorted(book_sorted)

print(book_sorted)
print(isbn_sorted)

### I WANT THE ISBN VALUE TO STICK W THE SORTED BOOK

### WHAT SHOULD I DO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `key` argument of the sorted function and the `operator.itemgetter` function from the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
import operator


def sort_books(books_borrowed, isbn):
    zipped = zip(books_borrowed, isbn)
    sorted_zipped = sorted(zipped, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    return list(zip(*sorted_zipped))

>>> sort_books(
...     ["lord of the rings", "Dune", "h2g2"], 
...     ["ltr_isbn", "d_isbn", "h2g2_isbn"]
... )
('Dhune', 'h2g2', 'lord of the rings'), ('d_isbn', 'h2g2_isbn', 'ltr_isbn')
```

[here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) is some more documentation on how to sort in python

Comment: You could get rid of the `list(...)` and write directly `zipped = zip(books_borrowed, isbn)`, which would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: PS [Frank Herbert's book has no h](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44767458-dune)

Comment: indeed, I was trying to stick to the code of the og question, changed it